# What characters are rejected during this check constraint clause in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

I tried to import a record with a semicolon in the addr field. Once I removed the semicolon from the import file, the following error went away:

> Database error occurred SQLSATE = 23000
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "addr_customer". The conflict occurred in database "db",table "dbo.customer", column 'addr'.

The stored procedure has this passage. I'm trying to understand in the `LIKE` clause, what other characters the constraint check is looking for. Obviously semicolon is disallowed. Do I read the clause where each character listed between `'%[` and `']%` are the disallowed characters (e.g. " | ; % _ ' )?

```
TABLE [dbo].[customer]  WITH 
CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[addr_customer] 
CHECK  ((NOT [addr] like '%[,"|;%_'']%'))
```

Answer (score 5):

This `CHECK` constraint verifies that the value does *not* match the `LIKE` pattern.

The pattern is evaluated as follows

- `%` start with any, multiple or no characters
- `[,"|;%_'']` any of the actual characters *within* the brackets (not including the brackets), and the `'` is doubled due to escaping.
- `%` followed with any, multiple or no characters

So essentially, the value cannot contain any of the characters `,"|;%_'`.

It also allows `NULL`s to be inserted, assuming there is not also a `NOT NULL` constraint.